# Matchmaking claiming I have to reconnect to a finished game

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Today I played 2 competitive matches in CS:GO. After the first competitive match ended, and tried to start the second game, it told me I still had a game going, and should reconnect from the main menu. Of course, reconnecting to a finished game does not work, so I opted for abandoning, causing a 10 minute cooldown.

After the cooldown, I did a second game. We won that game, and in the lobby for the third we all got the same message. I also noticed the win did not get added to my total win counter.

Is there anything I can do to let matchmaking know that the game has finished, or am I forced to either abandon and accept the ban, or just wait around until it eventually resolves itself?

Comment: when the competitive game finishes do you wait until it returns you back to the lobby? or do you quit before that? Have you tried closing and reopening the game?

Comment: I wait until the game kicks me back to the main menu, or the lobby in this game. The reconnect message does not show up on the main menu until you restart the game.

Comment: That's strange, I'd suggest possibly reporting it to Steam. You can also try verifing the game cache integrity (close cs, go to steam library right click > properties on CSGO, click local files then verify.)

Comment: Me and my friend had this on Monday and he started a local match against bots which seemed to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an ongoing issue as reported on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/GlobalOffensive/comments/3nls8t/reconnect_or_abandon_after_game/). There is currently no fix for it at the moment.

This is also tied to Steam as CS:GO steam services are experiencing massive delays (upwards of 2hrs).  You'll have to wait until Valve pushes out a fix for it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Many people have reported this issue, some people have said that verifying the game cache fixes the issue for them. You could try doing that it may work.

To verify the game Cache:

- Close CS:GO
- Go to Steam Library
- Right click on CS:GO and select *Properties*
- Click Local Files
- Click Verify Game Cache
- Relaunch CS:GO